# Отсттупы CSS не соответствуют коду

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток.

Нужны отступы как в коде, на деле получаются ощутимо больше. Памагити

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 53px;
}

.title {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f9bf3b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2.title {
  /* margin-top: 5px; */
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.simple .title_big {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* margin-top: 7px; */
  margin-top: 21px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Создать свой сайт на WordPress </h1>

<div class="simple">
  <h2 class="title_big">это просто</h2>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<h2 class="title">Куда сложнее сделать это правильно!</h2>
```

Comment: поясните где отступ больше чем нужно

Comment: @PavelGrishaev h2 class="title_big".Причем только для этого элемента подключается user agent stylesheet.  </br>      display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-block-start: 0.83em;
    margin-block-end: 0.83em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;    Прошу прощения за форматирование, почему-то не ставится ни перенос строки, ни ctrl+k   Пытался подкюлчить reset.css, отступы изменяются, но не становятся желаемыми

Comment: вообще, с h2 class=title похоже такая же проблема

Comment: У многих элементов есть стили по умолчанию, которые надо вручную менять или использовать ресет. Например `margin-block-start` перебивается с помощью `margin-top`. А желаемым отступ станет когда сойдётся `line-height` и прочие маргины и паддинги. Вычислить самому это бывает сложно (символ гуляет по высоте), можно подгонять не смотря на точные значения. И программы дизайна часто показывают неверный отступ, вернее не тот, который будет в реальности в вёрстке.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev я понял, всё не так просто, как кажется...Спасибо!